# How to structure MSI for .NET .DLL with shared dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, wix

I am creating two separate MSI installation packages using WIX: #1. a web service, #2. `.dll`. Both comes with number of dependencies, some of which are share, such as `log4Net` and others.`.dll` will be installed into GAC and will be used by web service and other services as well, i.e. it is reusable component.

What I am not sure, is how to structure installation of `.dll`s MSI, so when `.dll` is used by services, .NET runtime would go out and look for it's dependencies in it's installation folder under`D:\DATA\XYZ` and possibly, not in the folder of the services this calling it.

Comment: A default service runs as System Account with no Environmental Variables.  So it may not have he credentials to access some files.  Often Services are run as Admin so they have the proper credentials.  You can add the installation path to the Environmental Variables so the dll can find the path of the installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

Don't waste your time deduplicating deps like log4net, the ROI on that non nonsensical effort is immeasurable. For those which are installed in the GAC, if the component ID is the same, the installation / uninstallation will work as expected. If app A is installed with it, then app B is installed with it, the component ref count will increment up to two. If either is uninstalled, the component ref count will decrement but still remain above 0, the dependency will be acknowledged and the component will remain.